# MyEclipse and build.xml/JRE misconfiguration

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

Every time I need to redeploy a project in particular, I get the following error:

[image: Error when deploying a particular project]

The workaround I found is right clicking on the build.xml file of the project > Run As... > External Tools Configuration > JRE tab, and then change the runtime JRE (it doesn't seem to matter which I choose as long as I change it).
The problem is that I have to repeat this process every time I make a major change in the code of the project and redeploy it, otherwise I get the error shown in the screenshot.
I'm familiar with Eclipse@Linux but I have to use MyEclipse@Windows and a lot of things are new to me.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that in your project properties you have the wrong Java Compiler selected? One that is not installed on your computer?

Comment: I don't know, but I doubt it. The workspace has like 5 projects and all of them build/deploy fine, using any **Separate JRE**. I only have this really annoying problem with this one.